# Java - Error Sending ImageIcons from server to client via ObjectOutputStream read/writeObject()

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client, imageicon

Little background, currently trying to complete an assignment for my degree, trying to implement an 'Auction House' localhost server-client program in which clients can bid on items saved on the server. When a new client connects to the server the user has to register his/her name and then the server will send the client all the item information.

Currently all the other information sends correctly however when I try to send the images of the items to the clients via ObjectOutputStream the server always fails to send the ImageIcons, when I then disconnect the client I am met with this error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 53 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
   at AuctionClient.retrieveItemInformation(AuctionClient.java:365)
   at AuctionClient.main(AuctionClient.java:341)
```

I think it might have something to do with that Im trying to send ImageIcons directly through the output stream without utilising serialisable but our java lecturer told us that ImageIcon didn't require that to function properly so i'm unsure, any advice would be great! I will place the code for server/clients below!

Server thread code:

```
public ClientHandler(Socket socket, BiddingItem item1, BiddingItem item2, int number) throws IOException
{
    client = socket;
    outputImage = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
    output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    startedItem1 = item1;
    startedItem2 = item2;
    clientNumber = number;
    images = new ImageIcon[2];
    images[0] = startedItem1.getImage();
    images[1] = startedItem2.getImage();
}
```

Trying to send information to client:

```
public void run()
{
    //previous code...
    for (int i=0; i<images.length;++i)
    {
        try 
        {
            outputImage.writeObject(images[i]);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\n**ERROR: Unable to send Item " + i + " image to client!**");
        }
        try 
        {
            outputImage.flush();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            System.out.println("\n**ERROR: Unable to flush OutputObjectStream!**");
        }
    }
```

Client creating input stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException 
{
    //previous code
    try
    {
        txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT: Attempting to connect to server...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
        inputFromServer = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        inputImageFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outputToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx)
    {
        txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT-ERROR: Unable to connect to server! Exiting...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Function that client uses to accept information:

```
private static void retrieveItemInformation() throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT: Waiting for Item Information...");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    clientNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputFromServer.nextLine());

    item1Code = inputFromServer.nextLine();
    item1Desc = inputFromServer.nextLine();
    item1Deadline = inputFromServer.nextLine();
    item1AuctionValue = Double.parseDouble(inputFromServer.nextLine());

    item2Code = inputFromServer.nextLine();
    item2Desc = inputFromServer.nextLine();
    item2Deadline = inputFromServer.nextLine();
    item2AuctionValue = Double.parseDouble(inputFromServer.nextLine());

    item1Image = (ImageIcon)inputImageFromServer.readObject(); // READING IMAGE 1
    item2Image = (ImageIcon)inputImageFromServer.readObject(); // READING IMAGE 2

    txtBoxServerMessage.setText("DEBUG: FINISHED IMAGE");
    txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT: Information Recieved! Displaying...");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    comboItemSelect.addItem(item1Code);
    comboItemSelect.addItem(item2Code);
    txtBoxClientNumber.setText(String.valueOf(clientNumber));

    updateDisplay();

}
```

Cheers!

M

Comment: Did you try [ImageInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream.html) and ImageOutputStream for this?

Comment: @svasa I wasn't aware of its existance, is it implemented in a similar fashion to ObjectOutputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
outputImage = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
// ...
output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
```

You can't wrap a single OutputStream in two different wrappers.  Their individual states and buffering are not compatible.

In particular, if you write even a single byte using anything other than your ObjectOutputStream, the object stream is corrupted.

If you want to send both objects and text, you can write a String object to the ObjectOutputStream.  You also can call ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF directly.

Comment: Hi @VGR, thanks for the quick response.

If I used the ObjectOutputStream and then closed it, could I then wrap the PrintWriter around the output stream and then use it?

Comment: No.  Once the stream is closed, it's closed for good, and can't be used again.

Comment: Ahh I apologise for my confusion, I wasn't aware that ObjectOutputStream could write Strings using .writeUTF, I will give that a go, thanks for the help!

Comment: As I mentioned, you can also pass a String to ObjectOutputStream.writeObject.

Comment: I've altered my code to use only Object output/input streams, I have tested that the other information goes through, but now if I try to send image Icons I'm met with an java.io.EOFException?

Comment: You should probably ask a brand new question, and include both the new client code and the new server code in it.

Comment: I have created a new question: 35584450

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, deleted the Printwriter & Scanner streams and replaced them with Object streams in both the clients and the Server and utilised the .writeObject & readObject methods, I also needed to ensure that the paths for the images were correctly implemented. Thanks for the help!